# Select2 won't load remote json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have an API that is called by Select2 (v4.0.5) however the debug message in the console says:

> Select2: The AJAX results did not return an array in the `results` key of the response.

When I review the documentation at [Select2's documentation site](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats) I seem to be following it correctly. This is the javascript I use on the webpage:

```
$('#account_id').select2({
  debug: true,
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  dataType: 'json',
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/account-query',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        v: "new"
      }
      return query;
    },
  }
});
```

This is the response from the API (sensitive bits redacted):

```
{
  "results": [{
    "id": "redacted-1",
    "text": "text redacted 1"
  },{
    "id": "redacted-2",
    "text": "text redacted 2"
  },{
    "id": "redacted-3",
    "text": "text redacted 3"
  },{
    "id": "redacted-4",
    "text": "text redacted 4"
  },{
    "id": "redacted-5",
    "text": "text redacted 5"
  }]
}
```

If I take the select2 code and supply it with the static json response (without results prepended, just the array) it works just fine.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of select2 are you using?

Comment: @lealceldeiro 4.0.5, I'll put it in the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and as expected I was overlooking a simple aspect:

Content-Type header needed to be application/json vs text/html

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the `processResults` callback function so Select2 able to render result in proper way.

I have created a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/shcavbng/) demo that doing the same.

```
$('#account_id').select2({
  debug: true,
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  dataType: 'json',
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
    data: function (params) {
    console.log('params =>' , params);
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        v: "new"
      }
      return query;
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      console.log('results =>' , data);
      data = data.data.reduce(function(o,i){o.push({id:i.id,text:i.first_name});return o;},[]);
       console.log('results =>' , data);
      return {
        results: data
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: My API response is already in the correct format, I shouldn't have to process the results and get it into the same format it is already in, unless I am missing something?

Comment: In the question description you have mention that the API response doesn't include `results` key. `Select2: The AJAX results did not return an array in the results key of the response.`

Comment: Did you look at my API response? It clearly shows the results key, right? If not, how should the API response be structured? Thanks.

Comment: add `processResults` callback and first console log to see what value you are getting if it's different then structure like this `data = data.data.reduce(function(o,i){o.push({id:i.id,text:i.first_name});return o;},[]);.`

Comment: The structure I get back matches select2 documentation

Comment: It's strange that it's not working. can you provide an jsfiddle demo so that i can able to debug

Comment: Unfortunately the API is internal network so I won't be able to or I'd be happy to! But I agree with you, I'm not sure what else to try at this point.